# Android - How to change header/footer view elements for existing ListView?

Tags: java, android

Say I add a header view to my list view using the typical method like so:

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
TextView headerText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
headerText.setText("This is my header!");

myListView.addHeaderView(header);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then, later I need to alter the text of the header textview...

```
TextView headerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
headerText.setText("new header text!");
```

This doesn't appear to work, since the way I originally attached the header to the list was by inflating it...

How do I change the text?

Comment: why are you second time get header textview resultCode TextView headerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview); ? just use the first one directly to setText.

Comment: post whole activity code so its easy to us understanding the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should simply store the reference to headerText that you used originally. Then call `setText` on it later.

Comment: This is the approach I ended up taking. But because the `headerText` was retrieved from an inflated View, I had to also store the reference to the inflated View. It worked though!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you executing the code to change the header text? If your not doing it on the UI thread the textview won't update.